# python-MySQLdb iphone

Tags: iphone, python, compilation, arm, mysql-python

Does anybody know where to get python-MySQLdb compiled for the arm iPhone architecture? or how to do it?
I'm stucked at this point:

```
:~/MySQL-python-1.2.3 root# python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -undefined dynamic_lookup -dynamiclib build/temp.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/arm-apple-darwin/lib/ -L/private/var/root/mysql/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lm -o build/lib.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/_mysql.dylib
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'arm-apple-darwin9-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the previous problem.....it was the threadsafe = True in site.cfg i had to put False.
Now i have another problem really similar

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -undefined dynamic_lookup -dynamiclib build/temp.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/arm-apple-darwin/lib/ -L/private/var/root/mysql/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lm -o build/lib.darwin-10.5-arm-2.5/_mysql.dylib
ld: library not found for -lm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'arm-apple-darwin9-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Which Library is needed for -lm?? (for example for -lz it needs zlib library).